# if statement or/not what to do? Gmail google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Im trying to add two different labels on emails. If the email contains "Production" OR "License" it should send an email and label it with "SentLabel2".

If the mail does not contain "Production" OR "License" it should just label it with another label "NotSentLabel2" .

**The problem:**
It labelsall email with "NotSentLabel2"

```
var sub = message.getSubject();
    var res = sub.match(/Production/g);
    var res2 = sub.match(/License/g);

    if (labels == undefined){

      if (res == "Production"){
        GmailApp.sendEmail(from, "test", "ok sounds good :)");
              threads[i].addLabel(SentLabel2);

      }
       if (res2 == "License"){
        GmailApp.sendEmail(from, "test", "ok sounds good :)");
              threads[i].addLabel(SentLabel2);

      }
      if (res || res2 != "Production" || "License"){
                      threads[i].addLabel(NotSentLabel2);

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently your last statement is always true as `"License"` is a truthy value. you would want something like

```
if(res !== "Production" && res2 !== "License") {...
```

but seeing as you are using regex why not use the test and test for both at the same time

```js
var sub = "Production";



if (/(Production)|(License)/g.test(sub)) {
  
  console.log("matched")

} else {
  

  console.log("didn't match anything")
}
```

Comment: I tried both but neither works, this works tho, you got me on the right thing:
 if (res == "Production" || res2 == "License"){
        GmailApp.sendEmail(from, "test", "ok sounds good :)");
              threads[i].addLabel(SentLabel2);
    }

   
      else {
           threads[i].addLabel(NotSentLabel2);
      }